# Algorithm for checking if all subarrays have an unique element

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

How to check if all subarrays of the array contain at least one unique element for NlogN complexity, where N is the length of the array?

For example:

`3 1 2 1 2 5 6` - doesn't satisfy the property (`1 2 1 2` has no unique elements)

`1 2 1 3 1 4 1 5` - satisfies the property

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We want to help you with your specific problems, not just do your (home-)work. However, as it is we don't know what this problem is and thus how to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What does subarray mean for you and what does "unique element" mean - your example doesn't help at all

Comment: If you mean "subarrays" to mean "any subset of the elements of the array", and does not need to be proper, this would amount to checking if all elements are unique.

Comment: @d'alar'cop I mean 'subarray' in the same sense as, for example, here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem or as in slices in python. 'Unique element in subarray' means there is only one such element in the subarray

Comment: @FrankW I have tried to use balances trees (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap to be exact) to check if the intersection of two subarrays has an unique element, but it doesn't seem to work because I have to check all the subarrays (and there are O(N^2) of them)

Comment: @Ryan I mean a continuous slice: `A[i], A[i+1], A[i+2], ... , A[i+k]`

Comment: @questioner You should update your question with your clarifications. We shouldn't have to read the comments in order to understand your question.

Comment: @questioner show some research effort before posting it to the platform.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume subarray means continuous sequence. I know this problem from a programming contest.

You can use use a divide and conquer type approach. Consider a function `isGood(sequence)` that answers your question. `isGood()` must have access to a data structure that keeps the frequency of sequence's elements in sorted order. The least frequent element must be unique, otherwise the whole sequence itself breaks your rule. Consider this element to have position `SplitPoint` in your array. Note that now you only have to answer your question for `sequence[1...SplitPoint - 1]` and `sequence[SplitPoint + 1... N]` independently (they should both say GOOD). This is because the element at `SplitPoint` guarantees that all subarrays that contain it are alright.

Ideally, `SplitPoint` would be in the middle of the array (this would guarantee $N \log (N)$). Obviously, this may not happen in general. However, notice that the bulk of your computation in `isGood()` involves computing the frequency table. When you split the sequence into two and recurse on the parts, you don't have to rebuild the two frequency tables again. You can split the big one into two in $O(\text{the smaller one's size})$. Given that the smaller part is always less than half the total size, this guarantees $(N log(N)) * Q$ time, where $Q$ is the complexity of modifying the frequency of an element (you can get $log(N)$ with any BST). To see why, consider the process backwards: each time you're uniting two disjoint sets in complexity $O(\text{size of the smallest})$. The total size of all the sets is N, therefore if you keep an eye on a particular element, it can't be in the smaller part more than $log(N)$ times.

Comment: Intriguing!  I'm struggling to follow why this runs in $O(N \log N)$ time, though.  Can you elaborate?  If at each recursive call the split was into two pieces, one with just 1 element and the other with $N-1$ elements, we'd be in trouble.  Is there some explanation why that can't happen?  Is there a clean recurrence relation for the running time of this algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to calculate the subarray.If there is atleast one unique element in the whole array, then the array is good.

Comment: The question says `3 1 2 1 2 5 6` is not good. Note that 5 and 6 are unique in that array. How will you explain that?

Comment: There is: all subarrays contain at least one unique element, so your answer is wrong. WLOG let it be the first element that is unique and no more unique exists, then any subarray without first element fail.